# Centos does not install on unallocated space

Tags: linux, hard-drive, centos

I have a 1TB hard disk on which I installed Windows 8.  It has 100GB unallocated space. I have this partition on my Windows (click to enlarge):

[image: partition]

Now, I want to install CentOS 6.4 on the remaining 100 GB space. While installing, I chose custom disk layout and created "/" 30 GB partition.  But after that, it won't allow me to create any other partition of any size (neither "/boot" nor swap), with the following error:

> Could not allocate the requested partition: Partitioning Failed: Not enough space left to create partition

How can I solve this problem?  I just have 2 primary partitions.  I can have two other primary partitions, but Centos doesn't install.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Windows to create the empty partitions for CentOS, and then assign the appropriate resources in CentOS ?   I'm guessing that CentOS does not want to mess with your partition structure - not that I'm saying thats a good thing.

Comment: i create this unallocated partition in windows

Comment: I'm proposing you create multiple partitions (eg root and swap) in Windows and then simply assign these during the CentOS installation process.